# Prove specially rearranged alternating harmonic series converges to $\frac 12 \ln{\frac{4p}{q}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, conditional-convergence

By Leibnitz's test the alternating series is convergent.

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac 1n 
=\frac 12 \ln{\frac{4×1}{1}}$
\begin{align}
& \left(1-\frac 12- \frac 14\right)+\left(\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18\right)+...\\
& =\frac 12 \ln {\frac{4\cdot 1}{2}}
\end{align}
Let $\sum \sigma$ is a rearrangement of the alternating series.$\sum t$ is obtained by grouping it's terms in such  a manner that each group contains $p$ positive terms and $q$ negative terms. Prove that $\sum t=\frac 12\ln {\frac{4p}{q}}$

Comment: The notation $4\frac{1}{2}$ is usually intended for mixed fractions, not multiplication. You should do something to indicate it is multiplication. In general this and your answer are very hard to read. You should improve the formatting and include some words of explanation in your answer.

Comment: The result is simpler if we take p and q terms from the basic series 1-1+1/2-1/2+1/3-1/3... instead of the usual alternating series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$t_{(p+q)n}$
\begin{align}
& =\left(1+\frac 13+...+\frac{1}{2p-1}-\frac 12-\frac 14-...-\frac{1}{2q}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2p+1}+...+\frac{1}{4p-1}-\frac{1}{2q+2}-...-\frac{1}{4q}\right)+...+\left(\frac{1}{2p(n-1)+1}+...+\frac{1}{2pn-1}-\frac{1}{2q(n-1)+2}-...-\frac{1}{2qn}\right)\\
&=\left(1+\frac 13+...+\frac{1}{2pn-1}\right)-\frac 12\left(1+\frac 12+\frac 13+...+\frac{1}{qn}\right)\\ 
&=\left(1+\frac 12+\frac 13+...+\frac{1}{2pn}\right)-\left(\frac 12+\frac 14+...+\frac{1}{2pn}\right)-\frac 12(\gamma_{qn}+\ln{qn})\\
 &=(\gamma_{2pn}+\ln{2pn})-\frac 12(\gamma_{pn}+\ln{pn})-\frac 12(\gamma_{qn}+\ln{qn}) \\
& =\left(\frac 12\ln 2^2+\frac 12\ln\frac pq\right)+\left(\gamma_{2pn}-\frac 12\gamma_{pn}-\frac 12\gamma_{q n}\right)
 \end{align}
$\therefore \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}t_{(p+q)n}=\frac 12\ln{\frac{4p}{q}} $